# Magento 2 : How can I add my custom side bar below Summary side bar in Cart page?

Tags: magento2, cart, shopping-cart, magento2.4.1

In cart page I want to add custom side bar below Summary side bar. Please give me some suggestions. Thanks!

Comment: Do you want to add custom section after summary sidebar?

Comment: Yes, but the section needs to be same as side bar.

Answer (score 0):

This does not directly help you right away. But does provide you the knowledge to customize the checkout page however you want

https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/howdoi/checkout/checkout_overview.html

Comment: Thanks! @jimmy for your time.